# bottom tabs navigation blocks component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

i am using react navigation v5 lib `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs`

my bottom tabs does not rendering the way is suppose to be(as i think), here is the photos

it renders as:

[image]

what i think it suppose to be :

[image]

how to make my app as second pic
Edit : i may add `marginBottom` for every screen as solution, but is't the best solution?

Comment: Ciao, can you show relevant part of code you made?

Comment: it's just as the one in the react navigation documentation page

Comment: ```<Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"}>
        <Tab.Screen name="Orders"  component={Orders} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Messages"  component={Home} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Cart"  component={Cart} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Home"  component={Home} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: I didn't developed reac-navigation, but I think that bottom tab is located on a different z-index of the screen. So it appears on top of the screen. You could use marginBottom but I don't get the point? Why you want this particular rendering? I mean if screen content is longer than screen size, you have to scroll down the screen with or without marginBottom...

Comment: if i use z-index the bottom tabs gets behind the screen and it will become invisible.
and when i use `scrollview` it will reduce the same issue, @GiovanniEsposito thanks for trying to help